# Database drive Business rule engine

Tags: database

Technology stack: .NET

Problem Statement: Application has lots of business rule, any change in existing rule or addition of new rule requires the whole release cycle ( modification to the code followed by testing and deployment).

Requirement [Hard pressed]: Business user should be able to specify the business rules dynamically using a GUI

Options explored:

1. MS BRE, however bundled with Biztalk
2. .Net stack Open source business rule engines (likes of SRE, Drools.NET, NxBRE) – Most of them not active.
3. Adding rules in database and giving user a GUI to add/edit same, although this seems most promising I am not a fan of dynamic sql for reasons of sql injection and possible performance implications not to mention lack of unit test coverage and foreseable maintainence issues.
4. WF – not explored but AFAIK don’t have a runtime builder.
5. Purchasing a commercial rule engine is not an option

The requirement is for on-line system, any suggestions are most welcome.

Answer (score -1):

I have experimented for business rules with special table (in Postgres)

```
CREATE TABLE acces_to_tables
(
  rule_name name,
  table_name name,
  field_name name,
  field_acc_value integer,
  is_write boolean
)
```

and universal function:

```
 create_access_temp_view(table_name name, in_write_access boolean)
```

for generate TEMP VIEW to database tables  with limit conditions from acces_to_tables for current user before call SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE.

TEMP VIEW is not a usual solution, but very fast working.